# can you perform induction by assuming k and k+1 and showing difference is correct.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

for example

LHS: $1+2+3+4+5... =$ RHS: $n(n+1)/2$ is usually proved by base case 1
and assuming that it is true for $k$, and showing that $k(k+1)/2 + k+1$ is the same as $(k+1)(k+1+1)/2$.

However can we assume that the statement is true for k and true for k+1, 
and since $((k+1)(k+1+1)/2) - (k(k+1)/2)$ is $k+1$, it shows that the RHS always produces the correct difference. And since the base case is true, and the difference is always correct, by induction the RHS formula always holds.

Is this a valid proof by induction?

Comment: Yes this is a correct proof but not the idea underlying induction. While proving $P(k) \ \forall \ n\in \mathbb{N}$ you have to check the base case and prove that $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$

Comment: but in my case i showed that the RHS worked for base case 1, and that since the difference is always correct for k and k+1, knowing that the RHS is correct for the base case of n=1 means it is correct for all natural numbers, isn't this the idea underlying induction?

Answer (score 2):

For this specific case, the two approaches (showing the result for $k$ implies the result for $k+1$, and showing the formulae for $k$ and $k+1$ differ by $k+1$) happen to be equivalent.

However, in general this approach is not valid. Assuming the thing you are trying to prove, and deducing a true statement from it, does not constitute a proof. You have to go the other way: start from something you know to be true, and deduce what you are trying to prove. Sometimes you can just reverse the steps of your non-proof to get a valid proof, but often the argument will not be reversible.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in this case i did not assume what i was trying to prove, i just wanted to show that the rate of increase of the formula n(n+1)/2 is the same as 1+2+3+4+5+... for any 2 successive natural values k. this means that the formula will always work

Comment: @palladius_wielki You asked about assuming the formula works for $k$ and $k+1$. The formula working for $k+1$ is what you need to prove, so you shouldn't assume it.

Comment: but in this case i am not proving k+1. I am proving that the formula always creates the correct difference